# Assembly crash report when casting UIView to SKView

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uikit, sprite-kit

I am making a simple game in SpriteKit, and I am trying to make a main menu using UIKit. I created a View controller for the main menu and a separate one for the game. Whenever the play button is pressed, it switches to the Game view controller, where that then presents the first scene. However, whenever it seems that whenever it attempts to cast the game view controller's UIView to and SKView to be able to present the scene, something fails, and crash report is assembly, which I have no idea how to debug. I believe it is instantiating the game view controller twice, because when I put a println() in the viewWillLayoutSubviews() method, it prints twice. Another post on this said the type was already of SKView during the cast, causing it to fail, in which case that might mean when it triggers twice, it casts once, then tries to cast again and fails. Thanks in advance!

Here is the swift code

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

class MenuViewController: UIViewController {
    let background = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "background.png"))
    let titleImg = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "title.png"))

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        background.frame = self.view.frame
        titleImg.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.width, 100)
        self.view.addSubview(background)
        self.view.addSubview(titleImg)
        let bp = ButtonPositions(controller: self)
        let play = button(bp.playY, named: "playButton.png")
        let leader = button(bp.leaderY, named: "leaderButton.png")
        let rate = button(bp.rateY, named: "rateButton.png")
        play.addTarget(self, action: "playPressed", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchDown)
        leader.addTarget(self, action: "leaderPressed", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchDown)
        rate.addTarget(self, action: "ratePressed", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchDown)
        self.view.addSubview(rate)
        self.view.addSubview(leader)
        self.view.addSubview(play)
     }

    func button(y:CGFloat, named name:String!) -> UIButton {
        let bp = ButtonPositions(controller: self)
        let img = UIImage(named: name)
        let b = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(bp.x, y, self.view.frame.width / 1.5, img.size.height))
        b.setImage(img, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        return b
    }

    func playPressed() {
        println("playPressed") //only prints once
       changeVC()
    }

    func changeVC() {
        self.presentViewController(GameViewController(), animated: true, completion: nil) //maybe initializing the GameViewController twice for some reason?
    }

    func leaderPressed() {

    }

    func ratePressed() {

    }

    func center() -> CGPoint {
        return CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.view.frame), y: CGRectGetMidY(self.view.frame))
    }

    override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}


class GameViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
        //prepareGame() 
        println("test") //this prints twice, even through the button press event is only triggered once
    }

    func prepareGame() {
            let skView = self.view as SKView //crashes here when called
            let scene = GameScene(size: self.view.bounds.size)
            skView.showsFPS = true
            skView.showsNodeCount = true
            skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
            scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
            skView.presentScene(scene)

    }

    override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
       return true
    }

    override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> Int {
        if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone {
            return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.AllButUpsideDown.toRaw())
        } else {
            return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.All.toRaw())
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: By definition casting can not fail. However you can cast to the wrong type, this is most likely what's happening here. If you have a UIView and cast it to SKView it won't make a SKView out of it, it will crash if you try to access any SKView property/method that UIView does not have. Check that self.view is really a SKView instance. A common cause is enabling iAd which for some reason replaces the view controller's view with its own.

Comment: A crash report shows stack traces and not assembly code. What you are seeing is Xcode showing you assembler code for the top stack frame of the crashing thread. You should provide a fully symbolicated crash report (e.g. by running the app without the debugger), otherwise you can get guesses or assumptions, but nothing more.

Comment: Oh ok. Thank you. I shouldn't have said crash report. When i run without the debugger, the button just freezes in the down position. When i tried let skView = self.view as? SKView, and printed, skView was nil...

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue. I created my project using the default Swift Game project for iOS which by default created the project for SceneKit, since I want to use SpriteKit and tried casting my new scene to SKView it produced EXC_BAD_ACCESS at the line were I tried to cast. To fix my problem I had to change the Class in the main storyboard to SKView since it was defaulted to SCNView.

Steps I followed to fix:

1. Select the main storyboard (in my case it was Main.storyboard)
2. Select the view from the hierarchy under View Controller
3. Select the Identity inspector tab (Utilities panel on the right)
4. Under the Custom Class section change the class from SCNView to SKView

After doing this the issue went away.

Comment: Oddly enough when I went to check which class the view was in the view controller, it was SKView... I resorted to just instantiating a brand new SKView and adding it as a subview to the view controller's UIView. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

This is not the most optimal way, but a temporary workaround was to create a new SKView and add it to the view controller's view. I was trying to avoid this because right at start of the scene the fps is around 40, and i see no reason why it shouldn't be 60 when there is nothing on the screen.

EDIT: adding a counter since the method was being called twice also helped with the fps

```
private var count = 0
private func prepareGame() {
    count++
    if count == 2 {
        let skView = SKView(frame: self.view.frame)
        self.view.addSubview(skView)
        let scene = GameScene(size: skView.bounds.size)
        skView.showsFPS = true
        skView.showsNodeCount = true
        skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
        scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
        skView.presentScene(scene)
    }
}
```